# How to add IPAD in wp_is_mobile()?

Tags: wordpress

When I access my site from an iPad, it displays the desktop version, and this is very annoying for the visitor, and the dimensions of the site are not correct. I wonder if I can make the iPad among the devices that show the mobile version and not the desktop version.

my site : wordpress
Detect device type : wp_is_mobile()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wp_is_mobile](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/) returns the result based on the requests user agent.

You can use the `wp_is_mobile` filter to add custom user agents to the list.

For example:

```php
function include_ipad_in_mobile_view( $is_mobile ) {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPad') !== false) {
        $is_mobile = true;
    }
    return $is_mobile;
}
add_filter( 'wp_is_mobile', 'include_ipad_in_mobile_view' );
```